# NtSetValueKey creates String but ValueData is not as specified

Tags: winapi

I am attempting to create a new string using NtSetValueKey, the string is created, but the ValueData is "garbage" rather than what is specified.

No doubt I'm doing something wrong, but I've looked at MSDN and tried to find some examples without success.

So here is the code snippet that calls NtSetValueKey

```
if (ObjectHandle != NULL) {

         UNICODE_STRING ValueName;
         UNICODE_STRING ValueData;

         RtlInitUnicodeString(&ValueName,
                     L"Test-String");

         RtlInitUnicodeString(&ValueData,
                     L"Some-Data");

         NtStatus = NtSetValueKey(ObjectHandle,
                                  &ValueName,
                                  0,
                                  REG_SZ,
                                  &ValueData,
                                  sizeof(ValueData));

         NtClose(ObjectHandle);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying `REG_SZ`, the `Data` argument needs to point to a null-terminated UTF-16 string, not to a `UNICODE_STRING` structure.  Your code is writing the contents of that structure (consisting of two length values and a pointer) into the registry, rather than the string the structure represents.

Your code should instead look something like this:

```
if (ObjectHandle != NULL) {

     UNICODE_STRING ValueName;

     RtlInitUnicodeString(&ValueName, L"Test-String");

     static const wchar_t ValueData[] = L"Some-Data";

     NtStatus = NtSetValueKey(ObjectHandle,
                              &ValueName,
                              0,
                              REG_SZ,
                              (PVOID)ValueData,
                              sizeof(ValueData));

     NtClose(ObjectHandle);
}
```

If you already have a `UNICODE_STRING` and you know it is null-terminated, you could do something like this:

```
      NtStatus = NtSetValueKey(ObjectHandle,
                              &ValueName,
                              0,
                              REG_SZ,
                              ValueData->Buffer,
                              ValueData->Length + sizeof(WCHAR));
```

If you have a `UNICODE_STRING` that isn't null-terminated, you will have to copy it into a buffer in order to null-terminate it.

Comment: Appreciate your response I had a feeling that I wasn't going to resolve this without some input - and I can see from your advice that this was the case. However before I posted this question I did spend some time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Just wondering if you can recommend a book / resource that would be useful reading / reference?

Comment: Nothing I can personally recommend, no.  But I believe Microsoft Press has various titles that might be relevant, and Google will find you any number of tutorials (of varying qualities).